# Great example of development architecture

Tags: .net, architecture

I am looking for a sample application which shows off good to great use of architectual patterns, so far I found

- [TailSpin](http://tailspintravel.codeplex.com/)
- [DinnerNow](http://www.dinnernow.net/)

The problem with the above is that the requirements to get this up, make it a nightmare to work with.

My requirements list is it should be simple to get up and running, covers the basics and does need to be in a .NET language.

Answer (score 2):

May not meet your need for simple to get going but take a look at

- [Who Can Help Me](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/)
- [Orchard](http://orchard.codeplex.com/) project.

Just reading about their architecture is a good start.

Grab a copy of Eric Evans DDD book for reading material as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Nerd Dinner](http://www.codeplex.com/nerddinner) for ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

I found out about the [The Northwind Starter Kit](http://nsk.codeplex.com/) through [this great book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X) by Dino Esposito, et. al.  Uses a layered, MVC Architecture and is very easy to setup.  Go to source code tab and download ready made Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET StockTrader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.aspx) example application from Microsoft, showcasing an enterprise SOA architecture.

Comment: Could not get this StockTrader to work ! Error: Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened. 
- Documentation does not mention anything about configuring this RSA thingy.

Comment: Try this (it worked for me): 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"

Answer (score 0):

I found Eric Evans DDD book to be the most inspiring book on Enterprise Application Architecture I have read so far. Reading this book, I have learnt more about Software Architecture than by studying any sample application.

As a side note, I wouldn't constrain myself to a .NET language. E.g. if you know C#, you'll find Java easy to read.

Saying this, there is a big community around DDD and they have a good sample application (in Java) on http://domaindrivendesign.org/.

Answer (score 0):

NDepend documentation comes with some pretty cool online blog posts, articles and white books concerning architecture of .NET code:

[Advices on partitioning code through .NET assemblies](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies.aspx)

[Control Components Dependencies to gain Clean Architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies)

[Re-factoring, Re-Structuring and the cost of Levelizing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing.aspx)

[Evolutionary Design and Acyclic componentization](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/22/evolutionary-design-and-acyclic-componentization.aspx)

[Layering, the Level metric and the Discourse of Method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx)

[Fighting Fabricated Complexity](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/06/28/fighting-fabricated-complexity.aspx)